# What are the difference-in-differences dealing with the treatment being turned off?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

The generalized Difference-in-Differences being used to deal with staggered implementation of laws in different countries (multiple groups and multiple time periods). And due to the heterogeneous implementation ( explained by [Goodman-Bacon, 2018](http://goodman-bacon.com/pdfs/ddtiming.pdf)), econometrics emerges some papers to solve the heterogeneous problems like [Gardner,2021](https://jrgcmu.github.io/2sdd_current.pdf), [Callaway and Sant'Anna (2020)](https://pedrohcgs.github.io/files/Callaway_SantAnna_2020.pdf).

I am wondering is there any method deal with the problem that the treatment turn off after being turned on?

Comment: Does my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/536231/what-might-be-the-identification-challenges-with-a-generalized-did-model-where-t) offer any insight?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Yé, it did, thanks a lot, Thomas